# Retargeting animation with gizmos, delete gizmos in action editor or export without them

Tags: animation

I am retargeting animation which works great. I select MODEL1 then MODEL2 and apply the animation of MODEL2 to MODEL1 in `dopesheet` -> `action editor`. Everything works great.

The problem is that MODEL2 has around 10 gizmos, which also are seen in the action editor as animations, they indeed hold the same animation, so I have it 10 times.

Because of this my file becomes really large. I need to export it as .fbx. I need to delete all gizmos. I tryed deleting them from the world before applying the animation, but that didnt helped.

The only way I can delete them if I select every gizmo one by one, unlink it and reload the file. That is very very time consuming. If one model has 8 animations, I need to select 80 gizmo animations manually. There must be a better way to do it.

Here are some images
World, thats the model which holds the animations which I want to use on an other model:
[image]

Here is my model the action editor and animations it got after retargeting:

[image]

I only need GhostCastSpell, the other things also hold animation data, depending which animation gizmo I select it does animate, but the model is offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many different approaches I found a solution myself.

To seperate the animations you want, you have to put them in NLA tracks and when exporting to .fbx you must go to `animations` and uncheck `all actions`:

[image]

It will only export the animations from the NLA tracks

To add animations to NLA tracks you have to open `dope sheet` -> `action editor` in one window and NLA Editor in the other. Then you have to select each animation which you want to keep one by one in the action editor and add it to an NLA track on the NLA editor. You have to add them to the armature not the mesh.

Here is how it has to look:

[image]